# How i can read simply console output

Tags: c++, winapi, console, char

it sounds very simple, but I have not found the method to be correct
I write

```
cout << "Hello world" << endl;
```

I see

```
Hello world
```

I want get for example second char 'e'

Method like

```
GetConsoleChar(1,0) //gives us char 'e'
```

Does this exist?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do. It sounds like you want to **output** something, but from inside the same program, treat it as **input**? In which case, just pass it around inside your program?

Comment: Getting chars outputted to console sounds like a bad idea. Why not save the string in a variable and then operate on it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but you meant `cin` ([documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/))?

Comment: Do you wanna access the output of your program or do you wanna read in some single chars or values? That sounds a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @BoBTFish i want to read **console output**

Comment: @AndriiKyriienko There is no such thing as **console output**. If you mean the standard output stream; the problem is in the name (its an output stream). Its write only. Also the standard output does not necessarily go to a terminal (it could be a file) so the concept of a screen position does not apply (that mapping is done by the console and is well beyond the borders of the application). If you want to read and write from a window your application has to create and control the window so that it can accesses it, or you need to use OS specific API to get accesses to an attached console.

Comment: The question is clearly tagged "winapi" and "console" and clearly wants to read the console output, i.e. the active console screen buffer, not a C/C++ stream. The initial standard handles for a console have read-write access because the console API requires this for functions such as `GetConsoleMode`, `SetConsoleMode`, and (relevant here) `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use winapi function called `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`.

Example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;

    HANDLE consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    char characterFromConsole;

    COORD positionInBuffer;
    positionInBuffer.X = 0; // Column number
    positionInBuffer.Y = 0; // Row number

    DWORD numberOfCharactersReaded = 0;

    DWORD numberOfCharactersToRead = 1;

    ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(
                consoleHandle,
                &characterFromConsole,
                numberOfCharactersToRead,
                positionInBuffer,
                &numberOfCharactersReaded);

    std::cout << characterFromConsole << std::endl;
}
```

In output you will recieve character in first row and first column, which in our case is `H`.

You'll find more informations about in [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter).

Comment: Can u pls explain me how to use it, I'm not strong in winapi. Just simple example. I would be very grateful

Comment: @AndriiKyriienko I've added example in my answer.